# "Scotch for 'a local beak'"

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's said in the movie, *The 39 Steps*.

What does *Scotch* mean in this case?

> "He's our Sheriff Substitute.  Scotch for 'a local beak'."

Comment: Tip: What research have you done? Have you searched Google for this, or looked in any dictionaries? If so, please tell us what you found and what still didn't make sense.

Comment: General Reference. Scotch = Scottish = the dialect spoken in Scotland. Beak is an old (slang?) word for a magistrate (or schoolmaster).

Comment: Okay, the dictionaries I researched didn't mention about it being equal to Scottish.. Only whisky and so on.. Thanks!!

Comment: http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=scotch

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_a_judge_called_a_beak),

> During the bubonic plague, judges visiting prisons used to wear primitive gasmasks, stuffed with herbs or spices thought to ward off the plague - since it looked like a beak... they were referred to as "going before the beak" as they were never seen without it.

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_a_judge_called_a_beak#ixzz1yZ9KaNLI

Find more information (including pictures) about this primitive gasmask here: [Plague doctor costume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_doctor_costume) (Wikipedia).

More interesting speculations about the origin of the term [here](http://www.businessballs.com/clichesorigins.htm).

Answer (score -3):

"The beak" is slang for a judge or someone in a position of authority. And scotch has nothing to do with scottish or whisky. And Scotch refers to the whisky not being scottish unless you want to offend that is.
Scotch used in this way mean to dismiss an idea. For example if i asked a friend if he fancied a pint and he said he was broke till pay day i might say "Scotch that idea then". This site explains it better:[scotch usage](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sco2.htm)

Comment: In this case, however, Scotch is used specifically to mean Scottish.